# Rewrite subdomains in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, cdn

Because I don't want to use CDN anymore I would like to rewrite cdn.example.com to www.example.com. How to do this with Nginx? There is only www.example.com in my server block.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    server_name cdn.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This assumes two things:

- That `cdn.example.com` DNS is pointed at the same place `www.example.com`
- That content served from CDN is being hosted on www under the same paths